# Change lock screen imsge in Windows 10 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

to be short and sweet I am trying to create a Powershell script that changes the background lock screen image in Windows 10.  Have done my research and here is what I found:

```
    $path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization" 
$img =  "Lock Screen File Path"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name LockScreenImage -value $img
```

This is something simple that would accomplish my goal HOWEVER it points to the registry and my opinion is changing the registry is not the way to do it.  Upon more research, I found another file path:

```
        $path = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\{SID}\ReadOnly\LockScreen_B"
```

No access to this path.

What is a simple way USING Powershell to change the lock screen on Windows 10 without messing with the registry?

Comment: What is wrong with updating the registry? That is where the value for the lock screen image is stored. To update the folder path you may have to elevate Powershell as Admin for access.

Comment: The personalization folder does not exist in the registry.  I can create it and make it work but my thoughts imaging systems often is to not customize registry settings unless if a last resort.  I can manually go to personalize>lock screen and click to change it but wanted to include it in a list of things to do in a script after putting a fresh image on the system.

Comment: If you change your mind and be able to change registry, you can use module which do exactly what you wanted:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.PSSetLockScreen/

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell, the easiest way **is** to amend the registry entry, but there are a few other options available.

Let's start with the dreaded registry entry:

```
Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Just change the above `$value` variable to the path of the image you want to use as the desktop background.

You can also change the "theme" for the desktop using the below CMD line (can also be run in Powershell):

`rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""YOUPATH to the .theme"""`

Just point it to the right path for the custom theme you want to set.

Last option was an EXE I found, but can't really confirm the validity of it so I won't link it (also doesn't fit the Powershell criteria!).

**Note**: I know you said to NOT edit the registry, but this really is the easiest way to go. If you find yourself doing this too much, add the registry entry and even the image file into your build image, though that might be overkill.